# Compare dates with current date in a GridView in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, view, grid

I have a GridView with Date column in the data bound field. I have to compare this date with the current date. If gridview date exceeds 24 hrs then row color should change as red. Can anyone pls help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must add event handler to [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event. In this event you can compare your date field

Answer (score 1):

Handle the OnRowDataBound event; something like this:

```
  protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
  { 
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DateTime myDate = (DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DateProperty");
        if(DateTime.Now.Substract(myDate).TotalHours>24)
        {
            e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
  }
```

Note: *NOT* tested but that's the idea.

Comment: @Aberdeen I am afraid that "is not working" tells me much as to be able to help you further. Provide more details in your question. how and what's failing, post the markup and the code behind, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. your solution is working ok. Just ignore my earlier post. Thanks again